# English word order

Tags: word-order, prepositional-phrases

I will be glad if you help me to find the answer to this question. Which is right?

> My brother was born on Monday, November 18th, 1986 at 12 o'clock in Pavlodar

or:

> My brother was born in Pavlodar at 12 o'clock on Monday, November 18th, 1986?

Also might you suggest any other options?

Comment: In this case, you can order these things pretty much any way you want. They are all "equal" facts regarding your brother's birth.

Comment: you have Place, Date, Time, so there are 6 possible sentences, all of which are okay grammatically

Comment: Note: 'Monday' and 'November 18th' are in apposition so rearranging them is trickier than the others.